# How to solve name duplication problem in inputs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I'm using a React Hook Form hook called useFieldsArray.

It renders an array of fields, in which each field has an object with the data that will be sent through the input.

Then you can dynamically add and remove fields. That is, you can add a field containing five inputs and each field will be an item in the array of fields.

I have a problem that when selecting a user in the first field, it is added to everyone. And these other fields are still validating as empty, so just adding one more name, they stop validating.

But the problem remains, because when selecting a name, they appear for everyone:

[image]

You can see the problem in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-morning-7vfryg?file=/src/App.tsx

My goal is that when I add a name to the auto complete, it is linked only to the specific auto complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an *array of fields*, each field needs to control its own states. You cannot use the same state `result` for all fields rendered.

In my experience with react-hook-form and validators (like zod and yup), **the best way to design your form data is to avoid the use of external states** (`useState`, or any other state management), all form data that is changed by user needs to be in your `useForm`. In that case, `result` is a duplicated state of the form state.

Here is a fixed [version in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-hamilton-eyjttc?file=/src/App.tsx) of your form with validation and multiple selected data working properly.